# can htaccess file define different RewriteBase for production and dev servers

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have htaccess files that use different RewriteBase on production and dev (windows) pc.

Currently I change the RewriteBase manually when deploying.

Can this be done automatically with some definition? The dev servers is windows 7 and production is Linux.

Here is an excerpt:

```
# !!! Change here between local host and production server!!!
# for local dev server
RewriteBase /app.xxx.com
# for production server
#RewriteBase /
```

Answer (score 0):

The [best practice](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) is to move your configuration directives to the actual Apache configuration file, and disallow .htaccess files completely.

That means you can simply copy all files from DEV to PROD without manual changes.